# How to fix error while loading shared libraries: "libpython3.6m.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"?

Tags: python-3.x, shared-libraries, fedora

I have an error after upgrade Fedora 30 version. I try to run my Django project,  but I got an error like

```
python: error while loading shared libraries: libpython3.6m.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 7):

Copy the library file `libpython3.6m.so.1.0` to your `/usr/lib/`. If you have downloaded Python3.6.x and installed it manually you will find the file `libpython3.6m.so.1.0` in the folder where you've extracted Python3.6.x or in `/usr/local/lib/`.
That worked for me under Debian 8.

Answer (score 5):

For Python 3.6, I was able to fix this by simply installing the lib, as:

```
sudo apt-get install libpython3.6-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it by installing `libpython3.6`:

```sh
sudo apt-get install libpython3.6
```